# Switching into weight paint mode makes objects uneditable

Tags: rigging, armature, vertices, weight-painting

I am currently trying to rig a character I have been working on for the last week, and I am running into a bug where as soon as I switch into weight paint mode, some of the objects/loose parts lose all their vertices, and can no longer be interacted with. You can still select their edges and faces, but you cant move them because their vertices just dont seem to exist anymore.[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? (at least a part of it): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Added a portion of the file. Simply switching to weight paint mode with the arm selected causes the issue to occur.

Comment: I could make it come back to normal with a alt H, not sure what's happening, it may be a bug

Comment: Thanks, ill try to manage with alt+H. No clue whats causing it. I cant seem to recreate the bug on another mesh, but cant seem to stop it on this one.